# Utilizar %(limite)[^\n] no scanf é seguro para capturar strings?

Tags: c, scanf, buffer, buffer-overflow

Gostaria de saber uma maneira totalmente segura de capturar strings sem correr risco de *buffer overflow* ou qualquer outra ameaça.

Li muito sobre funções prontas e gostaria de saber quais são as mais recomendadas, mas eu queria poder implementar uma e saber como a coisa realmente funciona.

Até agora, achei uma boa utilizar o `%(limite)[^\n]` para capturar uma entrada até que o usuário tecle enter ou atinja uma quantidade (limite) de caracteres lidos. Para este caso, se o usuário continuar digitando ele encherá o *buffer* (certo ?), sendo assim, terei que limpar o *buffer* para a próxima leitura (certo?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O ideal seria utilizar a função `fgets`:

```
fgets(buffer, buffer_size, stdin);
```

Mas você pode não se limitar somente a ela, como pode ver abaixo:

[Max string length using scanf -> ANSI C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17314796/max-string-length-using-scanf-ansi-c)

[How to use sscanf correctly and safely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457325/how-to-use-sscanf-correctly-and-safely)

[How to prevent scanf causing a buffer overflow in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/how-to-prevent-scanf-causing-a-buffer-overflow-in-c)

Meu **palpite sobre a implementação** seria dar um loop entre 0 e o tamanho do buffer, e dentro desse loop utilizar `getchar()`:

```
char str[100];
size_t buffer_size = 100;
size_t i = 0;
while(i < buffer_size-1 && (str[i] = getchar()) != '\n')
  ++i; 
str[i] = '\0';
```

(Se eu precisasse, eu implementaria da maneira acima)

Como é implementada: [Implementação oficial(BSD)](http://code.google.com/p/retrobsd/source/browse/trunk/lib/libc/stdio/fgets.c?r=369)